# Prove commutative subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, group-theory, modular-arithmetic, abelian-groups

Let $K$ be the group consisting of all invertible $2\times2$ matrices with coefficients in $\mathbb Z/3\mathbb Z$. Here the group is the usual matrix multiplication, and the unit element is $e:=\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix} $

Consider the matrices $p:=\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\1&1\end{bmatrix} $

$l:=\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\0&2\end{bmatrix} $

Let $R:=\{h^ng^m : m,n \in \mathbb{Z}_{>0} \}$  and $F:=\{g\in G:\det(g)= 1 \pmod{3}\}$ are subgroups of $G$.

> Show that $R \cap F$ is a commutative group.

I have shown that it is a subgroup, but I don't know how to show that for all $x,y\in(J\cap H)$ we have $xy=yx$.

Could somebody please help me? Thank you!

Comment: The following is a start on the problem but I got stuck . . .

Comment: Let $x, y\in I:= J\cap H$. Then $x=g^{\xi_1}h^{\xi_2}$ and $y=g^{\upsilon_1}h^{\upsilon_2}$ for some $\xi_i, \upsilon_i\in \Bbb N$. Moreover, $\det(x)=det(y)=1\pmod{3}$. (1/3)

Comment: Consider $xy$. We aim to show $\det(xy)=1\pmod{3}$ and there exist $\zeta_i\in\Bbb N$ such that $xy=g^{\zeta_1}h^{\zeta_2}$. (2/3)

Comment: It would help, then, to know what the powers of $g$ and $h$ are. (3/3)

Comment: Try writing a presentation for $G$ with $g$ and $h$ as generators.

Answer (score 1):

Let $F=\Bbb F_3$ be the field with three elements. Then
$$
\begin{aligned}
G &= \operatorname{GL}(2,F) \ ,\qquad &|G| &= (3^2-1)(3^2-3)=48\ ,\\
H &= \operatorname{SL}(2,F) \ ,\qquad &|H| &= |G/\pm1|=|G|/2 =24\ ,\\
<g> &= \{1,g,g^2,\dots, g^7\}\ & g&\text{ has order }8\ ,\\
<h> &= \{1,h\}\ & h&\text{ has order }2\ ,\\
hgh^{-1} &= g^3\ ,\\
J:=<g,h> &=\{1,g,g^2,\dots, g^7,\ h, hg, hg^2,\dots, hg^7\}\ & |J|&=16\ ,\\
\det g=\det h&=-1\ ,\\
J\cap H &=\{1,g^2,g^4, g^6,\ hg, hg^3,hg^5, hg^7\}\ ,
&|J\cap H|&=8\ ,\\
&=<g^2,hg>\ ,
\end{aligned}
$$
and we check the commutativity of the above two generators of $J\cap H$, using computations with final results in the above explicit list of elements, we use the relations $hgh^{-1} = g^3$ and $h^2=1$, so $hgh=g^3$, and $gh=hg^3$:
$$
\begin{aligned}
hg\cdot g^2 &= hg^3\ ,\\
g^2\cdot hg &=g\ gh\ g=g\ hg^3\ g=gh\ g^4=hg^3\ g^4\\
&= hg^7\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
The group $J\cap H$ with eight elements is thus **not commutative**.

---

Computer check, here [sage](https://www.sagemath.org):

```
sage: F = GF(3)    # the field with three elements
sage: G = GL(2, F)
sage: H = SL(2, F)
sage: g = matrix( F, 2,2, [0,1,1,1] )
sage: g.multiplicative_order()
8
sage: h = matrix( F, 2,2, [1,1,0,2] )
sage: h.multiplicative_order()
2
sage: h*g*h == g^3
True
sage: J = G.subgroup( [g, h] )
sage: J.order()
16
sage: J_cap_H = G.subgroup( [g^2, h*g] )
sage: J_cap_H.order()
8
sage: [ j.matrix().det() for j in J_cap_H ]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
sage: J_cap_H.is_commutative()
False
sage: h*g * g^2 == g^2 * h*g
False
```

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: it is enough to find a generating set for $J\cap H$ and to show that its elements commute. Three generators should suffice.